# SMTP quoted-printable soft line breaks vs. UTF-8 multi-byte sequences

Tags: smtp

When encoding an SMTP body with Content-Type `text/plain; charset=UTF-8` and Content-Transfer-Encoding `quoted-printable`, is it allowed to have a soft line break between two of the percent encodings of the bytes of a UTF-8 multi-byte sequence?

In other words, given that C3 A4 is the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding of U+00E4, is an SMTP body like `"=C3=\r\n=A4\r\n.\r\n"` allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly allowed. Quoted-printable doesn't care (and actually isn't *allowed* to care) what bytes you encode, or their semantics in any particular content type.

If you think about it, this byte sequence obviously has a completely different meaning in UTF-16 or GBK. In fact, the encoding should (and of course, can in fact) handle arbitrary binary data completely transparently.

Comment: Yes, in theory it wouldn't make sense for it to be otherwise, but in practice, with old-school protocols like SMTP, you never know, and I couldn't find it written out anywhere.